# Data-Target is not functioning with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, css, filter, addeventlistener

When a filter category is selected the active2 class gets added to the category adding a blue circle around the button. This function works for the menu itself. However, I have buttons on each card that are labeled 'alternative'. Once clicked they select the equivalent data target as if you were to select it from the categories at the top but the active2 class does not get added to the category.

For example, if you scroll down to the 'condoms 1' card and click alternative you will see that only the 'condom 1' card is shown but that the filter buttons at the top remain under 'all'. If you select condoms using the filter buttons at the top then you will see that 'condoms 1' is the only one that shows up and the condoms button will have a blue circle over it from the active2 class which is what I want to happen. I would appreciate any help or suggestions, thank you!

```js
function fn(query) {
  const filterButtons = document.querySelector(query).children;
  const items = document.querySelector(".machine__content").children;

  for (let i = 0; i < filterButtons.length; i++) {
    filterButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      for (let j = 0; j < filterButtons.length; j++) {
        filterButtons[j].classList.remove("active2");
      }
      this.classList.add("active2");
      const target = this.getAttribute("data-target");

      for (let k = 0; k < items.length; k++) {
        items[k].style.display = "none";
        if (target == items[k].getAttribute("data-id")) {
          items[k].style.display = "block";
        }
        if (target == "all") {
          items[k].style.display = "block";
        }
      }
    });
  }
}



fn('#filter-btns');
fn('#filter-machine');
fn('#filter-levo5');
fn('#filter-condoms');
fn('#filter-fem');
fn('#filter-other');
```

```css
/*=============== GOOGLE FONTS ===============*/

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lemon&family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600&display=swap");
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');

/*=============== VARIABLES CSS ===============*/

:root {
  --header-height: 3.5rem;
  /*========== Colors ==========*/
  /*Color mode HSL(hue, saturation, lightness)*/
  --hue: 112;
  --first-color: #38afff;
  --first-color-alt: hsl(204, 94%, 52%);
  --title-color: hsl(233, 32%, 15%);
  --text-color: hsl(233, 4%, 35%);
  --body-color: #daeef6;
  --first-hue: 250;
  --sat: 66%;
  --lig: 75%;
  --second-hue: 219;
  /*========== Font and typography ==========*/
  /*.5rem = 8px | 1rem = 16px ...*/
  --body-font: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  --second-font: 'Lemon', cursive;
  --biggest-font-size: 2.25rem;
  --normal-font-size: .938rem;
  /*========== z index ==========*/
  --z-tooltip: 10;
  --z-fixed: 100;
  --z-modal: 1000;
}

img {
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


/* Responsive typography */

@media screen and (min-width: 1224px) {
   :root {
    --biggest-font-size: 3.5rem;
    --normal-font-size: 1rem;
  }
}


/*=============== BASE ===============*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  background: var(--body-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#page-background {
  background: url(../img/shape-bg.webp);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  mix-blend-mode: soft-light;
}


/* Active link */

.active-link {
  color: var(--first-color);
}


/*=============== Filter ===============*/

.filter-buttons {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.filter-buttons ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

.filter-buttons ul li {
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.filter-buttons ul li.active2 {
  color: rgb(38, 38, 59);
  border: 2px solid var(--first-color);
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 2px 15px 2px 15px;
}


/*=============== Filter End ===============*/


/*=============== BLOG ===============*/

.blog__container {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.blog__content {
  row-gap: 3rem;
}

.blog__card {
  border: .11px solid whitesmoke;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px rgba(43, 31, 31, 0.228);
}

.blog__image {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
}

.blog__img {
  border-radius: .5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 16px hsl(355deg 25% 15% / 10%);
  display: block;
  border: .1px solid white;
}

.blog__image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.blog__image {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
}

.blog__img {
  border-radius: .5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 16px hsl(355deg 25% 15% / 10%);
  display: block;
  border: .1px solid white;
}

.blog__image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.blog__button {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1.15rem;
  border-radius: .5rem 0 .5rem 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: var(--title-color);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.blog__button i {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  transition: .4s;
}

.blog__button:hover i {
  transform: rotate(-30deg) translateX(.25rem);
}

.blog__title {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-bottom: .75rem;
  cursor: default;
}

.blog__description {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  cursor: default;
}

.blog__footer,
.blog__reaction {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.blog__footer {
  column-gap: 1.5rem;
}

.blog__reaction {
  column-gap: .25rem;
}

.blog__reaction i {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.blog__reaction span {
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bx {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*=============== Our Machines ===============*/

.machine__container {
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: .11px solid rgb(195, 239, 233);
  background-color: rgba(244, 247, 247, 0.891);
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px rgba(43, 31, 31, 0.228);
}

.machine__content {
  row-gap: 3rem;
}

.machine__card {
  border: .11px solid whitesmoke;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px rgba(43, 31, 31, 0.228);
}

.machine__image {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
}

.machine__img {
  border-radius: .5rem;
  display: block;
}

.machine__image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.machine__button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #38afff;
  color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: .3s;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.machine__button:hover {
  background-color: #3197db;
}

.machine__button i {
  transition: .4s;
}

.machine__button:hover i {
  transform: translateY(-.15rem) translateX(.15rem);
}

.machine__title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-bottom: .75rem;
  cursor: default;
}

.machine__data {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.machine__description {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  cursor: default;
}

.machine__footer,
.machine__reaction {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.machine__footer {
  column-gap: 1.5rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

.machine__reaction {
  column-gap: .25rem;
}

.machine__reaction i {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.machine__reaction span {
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bx {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <!--=============== CSS ===============-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/scroll_nav.css">





</head>

<body>

  <!--==================== BLOG ====================-->
  <section class="blog section__blog" id="blog">
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="blog__container container__blog">

      <!--==================== Filter ====================-->
      <br/>

      <div class="filter-buttons">
        <ul id="filter-btns">
          <li class="active2" data-target="all">All</li>
          <li data-target="mach">Machines</li>
          <li data-target="levo">Levonorgestrel</li>
          <li data-target="condoms">Condoms</li>
          <li data-target="fem">Feminine Hygiene</li>
          <li data-target="other">Other</li>

        </ul>
      </div>

      <br/>


      <div class="machine__content grid__blog">




        <article data-id="mach" class="machine__container">
          <div class="machine__image">
            <img src="assets/img/planb-products.png" alt="chart showing increase in stds" class="machine__img">
          </div>
          <div class="machine__data">
            <h2 class="machine__title">
              Machine 1
            </h2>
          </div>

          <br/>

          <div class="machine__footer">
            <div id="filter-machine">
              <a data-target="mach" href="#filter-btns" class="machine__button">
                <div class="blog__reaction">

                  <span>Alternative</span>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            </a>

          </div>





        </article>



        <article data-id="levo" class="machine__container">
          <div class="machine__image">
            <img src="assets/img/planb-products.png" alt="chart showing increase in stds" class="machine__img">
          </div>
          <div class="machine__data">
            <h2 class="machine__title">
              Levonorgestrel 1
            </h2>
          </div>

          <br/>

          <div class="machine__footer">
            <div id="filter-levo5">
              <a data-target="levo" href="#filter-btns" class="machine__button">
                <div class="blog__reaction">

                  <span>Alternative</span>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            </a>

          </div>





        </article>





        <article data-id="condoms" class="machine__container">
          <div class="machine__image">
            <img src="assets/img/trojanlogo.png" alt="chart showing increase in stds" class="machine__img">
          </div>
          <div class="machine__data">
            <h2 class="machine__title">
              Condoms 1
          </div>

          <br/>

          <div class="machine__footer">
            <div id="filter-condoms">
              <a data-target="condoms" href="#filter-btns" class="machine__button">
                <div class="blog__reaction">

                  <span>Alternative</span>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>

          </div>



        </article>







        <article data-id="fem" class="machine__container">
          <div class="machine__image">
            <img src="assets/img/durextest.png" alt="chart showing increase in stds" class="machine__img">
          </div>
          <div class="machine__data">
            <h2 class="machine__title">
              Feminine 1
          </div>

          <br/>

          <div class="machine__footer">
            <div id="filter-fem">
              <a data-target="fem" href="#filter-btns" class="machine__button">
                <div class="blog__reaction">

                  <span>Alternative</span>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>

          </div>

        </article>



        <article data-id="other" class="machine__container">
          <div class="machine__image">
            <img src="assets/img/durextest.png" alt="chart showing increase in stds" class="machine__img">
          </div>
          <div class="machine__data">
            <h2 class="machine__title">
              Other 1
          </div>

          <br/>

          <div class="machine__footer">
            <div id="filter-other">
              <a data-target="other" href="#filter-btns" class="machine__button">
                <div class="blog__reaction">

                  <span>Alternative</span>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>

          </div>

        </article>



      </div>
    </div>
  </section>



  <br/><br/><br/>



  </main>




  <!--=============== GSAP ===============-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/gsap.min.js"></script>


  <!--=============== MAIN JS ===============-->
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you combining the event listener for the menu items at the top with the event listener for the buttons in the rest of the page? This just makes it very confusing. _`this.classList.add("active2");`_ — `this` doesn’t refer to any of the menu items at the top when the listener is bound to the buttons below. You could select ``document.querySelector(`#filter-btns [data-target='${this.dataset.target}']`)`` in such a case, but there are probably easier ways to write this using event delegation.

Comment: @SebastianSimon sorry im just starting. Are you suggesting that I replace this.classList.add("active2"); with document.querySelector(`#filter-btns [data-target='${this.dataset.target}']`)? And where would I place what you said to include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without doing a complete refactor of your code, you can add a `click` listener to the `a[data-target]` elements that update the corresponding `li[data-target]` elements with the styling you want.

For easy reference, here is the JS added:

```js
const filters = document.querySelectorAll('li[data-target]')
const targets = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-target]')

for (const target of targets) {
  target.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const filterTarget = e.currentTarget.dataset.target
    const filter = document.querySelector(`li[data-target=${filterTarget}]`)
    
    for (const filter of filters) {
      filter.classList.remove('active2')
    }
    filter.classList.add('active2')
  })
}
```

```js
function fn(query) {
  const filterButtons = document.querySelector(query).children;
  const items = document.querySelector(".machine__content").children;

  for (let i = 0; i < filterButtons.length; i++) {
    filterButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      for (let j = 0; j < filterButtons.length; j++) {
        filterButtons[j].classList.remove("active2");
      }
      this.classList.add("active2");
      const target = this.getAttribute("data-target");

      for (let k = 0; k < items.length; k++) {
        items[k].style.display = "none";
        if (target == items[k].getAttribute("data-id")) {
          items[k].style.display = "block";
        }
        if (target == "all") {
          items[k].style.display = "block";
        }
      }
    });
  }
}



fn('#filter-btns');
fn('#filter-machine');
fn('#filter-levo5');
fn('#filter-condoms');
fn('#filter-fem');
fn('#filter-other');

const filters = document.querySelectorAll('li[data-target]')
const targets = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-target]')

for (const target of targets) {
  target.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const filterTarget = e.currentTarget.dataset.target
    const filter = document.querySelector(`li[data-target=${filterTarget}]`)
 
    for (const filter of filters) {
      filter.classList.remove('active2')
    }
    filter.classList.add('active2')
  })
}
```

```css
/*=============== GOOGLE FONTS ===============*/

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lemon&family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600&display=swap");
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');

/*=============== VARIABLES CSS ===============*/

:root {
  --header-height: 3.5rem;
  /*========== Colors ==========*/
  /*Color mode HSL(hue, saturation, lightness)*/
  --hue: 112;
  --first-color: #38afff;
  --first-color-alt: hsl(204, 94%, 52%);
  --title-color: hsl(233, 32%, 15%);
  --text-color: hsl(233, 4%, 35%);
  --body-color: #daeef6;
  --first-hue: 250;
  --sat: 66%;
  --lig: 75%;
  --second-hue: 219;
  /*========== Font and typography ==========*/
  /*.5rem = 8px | 1rem = 16px ...*/
  --body-font: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  --second-font: 'Lemon', cursive;
  --biggest-font-size: 2.25rem;
  --normal-font-size: .938rem;
  /*========== z index ==========*/
  --z-tooltip: 10;
  --z-fixed: 100;
  --z-modal: 1000;
}

img {
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


/* Responsive typography */

@media screen and (min-width: 1224px) {
   :root {
    --biggest-font-size: 3.5rem;
    --normal-font-size: 1rem;
  }
}


/*=============== BASE ===============*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  background: var(--body-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#page-background {
  background: url(../img/shape-bg.webp);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  mix-blend-mode: soft-light;
}


/* Active link */

.active-link {
  color: var(--first-color);
}


/*=============== Filter ===============*/

.filter-buttons {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.filter-buttons ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

.filter-buttons ul li {
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.filter-buttons ul li.active2 {
  color: rgb(38, 38, 59);
  border: 2px solid var(--first-color);
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 2px 15px 2px 15px;
}


/*=============== Filter End ===============*/


/*=============== BLOG ===============*/

.blog__container {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.blog__content {
  row-gap: 3rem;
}

.blog__card {
  border: .11px solid whitesmoke;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px rgba(43, 31, 31, 0.228);
}

.blog__image {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
}

.blog__img {
  border-radius: .5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 16px hsl(355deg 25% 15% / 10%);
  display: block;
  border: .1px solid white;
}

.blog__image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.blog__image {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
}

.blog__img {
  border-radius: .5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 16px hsl(355deg 25% 15% / 10%);
  display: block;
  border: .1px solid white;
}

.blog__image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.blog__button {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1.15rem;
  border-radius: .5rem 0 .5rem 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: var(--title-color);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.blog__button i {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  transition: .4s;
}

.blog__button:hover i {
  transform: rotate(-30deg) translateX(.25rem);
}

.blog__title {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-bottom: .75rem;
  cursor: default;
}

.blog__description {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  cursor: default;
}

.blog__footer,
.blog__reaction {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.blog__footer {
  column-gap: 1.5rem;
}

.blog__reaction {
  column-gap: .25rem;
}

.blog__reaction i {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.blog__reaction span {
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bx {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*=============== Our Machines ===============*/

.machine__container {
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: .11px solid rgb(195, 239, 233);
  background-color: rgba(244, 247, 247, 0.891);
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px rgba(43, 31, 31, 0.228);
}

.machine__content {
  row-gap: 3rem;
}

.machine__card {
  border: .11px solid whitesmoke;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px rgba(43, 31, 31, 0.228);
}

.machine__image {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
}

.machine__img {
  border-radius: .5rem;
  display: block;
}

.machine__image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.machine__button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #38afff;
  color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: .3s;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.machine__button:hover {
  background-color: #3197db;
}

.machine__button i {
  transition: .4s;
}

.machine__button:hover i {
  transform: translateY(-.15rem) translateX(.15rem);
}

.machine__title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-bottom: .75rem;
  cursor: default;
}

.machine__data {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.machine__description {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  cursor: default;
}

.machine__footer,
.machine__reaction {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.machine__footer {
  column-gap: 1.5rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

.machine__reaction {
  column-gap: .25rem;
}

.machine__reaction i {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.machine__reaction span {
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bx {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <!--=============== CSS ===============-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/scroll_nav.css">





</head>

<body>

  <!--==================== BLOG ====================-->
  <section class="blog section__blog" id="blog">
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="blog__container container__blog">

      <!--==================== Filter ====================-->
      <br/>

      <div class="filter-buttons">
        <ul id="filter-btns">
          <li class="active2" data-target="all">All</li>
          <li data-target="mach">Machines</li>
          <li data-target="levo">Levonorgestrel</li>
          <li data-target="condoms">Condoms</li>
          <li data-target="fem">Feminine Hygiene</li>
          <li data-target="other">Other</li>

        </ul>
      </div>

      <br/>


      <div class="machine__content grid__blog">




        <article data-id="mach" class="machine__container">
          <div class="machine__image">
            <img src="assets/img/planb-products.png" alt="chart showing increase in stds" class="machine__img">
          </div>
          <div class="machine__data">
            <h2 class="machine__title">
              Machine 1
            </h2>
          </div>

          <br/>

          <div class="machine__footer">
            <div id="filter-machine">
              <a data-target="mach" href="#filter-btns" class="machine__button">
                <div class="blog__reaction">

                  <span>Alternative</span>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            </a>

          </div>





        </article>



        <article data-id="levo" class="machine__container">
          <div class="machine__image">
            <img src="assets/img/planb-products.png" alt="chart showing increase in stds" class="machine__img">
          </div>
          <div class="machine__data">
            <h2 class="machine__title">
              Levonorgestrel 1
            </h2>
          </div>

          <br/>

          <div class="machine__footer">
            <div id="filter-levo5">
              <a data-target="levo" href="#filter-btns" class="machine__button">
                <div class="blog__reaction">

                  <span>Alternative</span>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            </a>

          </div>





        </article>





        <article data-id="condoms" class="machine__container">
          <div class="machine__image">
            <img src="assets/img/trojanlogo.png" alt="chart showing increase in stds" class="machine__img">
          </div>
          <div class="machine__data">
            <h2 class="machine__title">
              Condoms 1
          </div>

          <br/>

          <div class="machine__footer">
            <div id="filter-condoms">
              <a data-target="condoms" href="#filter-btns" class="machine__button">
                <div class="blog__reaction">

                  <span>Alternative</span>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>

          </div>



        </article>







        <article data-id="fem" class="machine__container">
          <div class="machine__image">
            <img src="assets/img/durextest.png" alt="chart showing increase in stds" class="machine__img">
          </div>
          <div class="machine__data">
            <h2 class="machine__title">
              Feminine 1
          </div>

          <br/>

          <div class="machine__footer">
            <div id="filter-fem">
              <a data-target="fem" href="#filter-btns" class="machine__button">
                <div class="blog__reaction">

                  <span>Alternative</span>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>

          </div>

        </article>



        <article data-id="other" class="machine__container">
          <div class="machine__image">
            <img src="assets/img/durextest.png" alt="chart showing increase in stds" class="machine__img">
          </div>
          <div class="machine__data">
            <h2 class="machine__title">
              Other 1
          </div>

          <br/>

          <div class="machine__footer">
            <div id="filter-other">
              <a data-target="other" href="#filter-btns" class="machine__button">
                <div class="blog__reaction">

                  <span>Alternative</span>

                </div>
              </a>
            </div>

          </div>

        </article>



      </div>
    </div>
  </section>



  <br/><br/><br/>



  </main>




  <!--=============== GSAP ===============-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/gsap.min.js"></script>


  <!--=============== MAIN JS ===============-->
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Notes**

- If possible you want to do a search only once or not at all, that is why you shouldn't put queries in functions that run multiple times.
- Use css classes instead of modifying styles directly because the browser can optimize paint and it reduces layout shift / calculations.
- For my JS to work, you need to add the following css

**CSS**

```css
.machine__container {
  display: block;
}

.machine__container.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```js
// Anonymous Function to contain variables
(() => {
    // Find all active Elements
    const filterMenu = [...document.getElementById("filter-btns").children];
    const filterItems = [...document.getElementsByClassName("machine__container")];
    const filterButtons = [...document.getElementsByClassName("machine__button")];

    // Process Click Event
    function handleAction({ currentTarget }) {
        const { target: targetId } = currentTarget.dataset;

        // Loop through menu items
        for (const menuElement of filterMenu) {
            const { target: menuId } = menuElement.dataset;
            if (targetId === menuId) menuElement.classList.add("active2");
            else menuElement.classList.remove("active2");
        }

        // Loop through data items
        for (const itemElement of filterItems) {
            const { id: menuId } = itemElement.dataset;
            if (targetId === "all" || menuId === targetId) itemElement.classList.remove("hide");
            else itemElement.classList.add("hide");
        }
    }

    // Add Event Listners to menu items
    for (const menuElement of filterMenu) {
        menuElement.addEventListener("click", handleAction);
    }

    // Add Event Listners to filter items
    for (const buttonElement of filterButtons) {
        buttonElement.addEventListener("click", handleAction);
    }
})();
```